# I need help s4dmessage.channel.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanna add after it gives me the random integer a "%", how do I do that?

```
function mathRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
                  
const randomInteger = `${mathRandomInt(1, 100)}%`;  
                  
s4d.client.on('messageCreate', async (s4dmessage) => {

  if ((s4dmessage.content) == '!homeless') {
       
    s4dmessage.channel.send(randomInteger);    
        
  }
```

i edited it , this is what i have and i get the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use backticks ( `` ) to access a variable in a string.
In order to use the variable, you need to surround it with : `${yourVariable}`

Inside your `client.on("messageCreate")` add this:

```
// added function example
function mathRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

const randomInteger = `${mathRandomInt(1, 100)}%`;
s4dmessage.channel.send(randomInteger);
```

Comment: i have a problem , i only get 33% everytime why? it only randomize the integer once

Comment: That's probably because of your `mathRandomInt()` function. See edited message

Comment: it generates a random integer in the original code everytime

Comment: Can you attach a snippet of it?

Comment: same issue , i still get the same integer everytime

Comment: how to attach it? i don't use stackoverflow that much

Comment: can we talk on discord maybe?

Comment: just edit your post by pressing the Edit button. It's right under your post's tags

Comment: i edited it , can u look ?

Comment: That happens because you're declaring your variable outside the event.
Move `const randomInteger = ``${mathRandomInt(1, 100)}%`;` inside your `client.on("mesageCreate")` event.

Comment: works perfectly! thx! i just started coding for the first time and i am strggling to make this bot , u helped me a lot <3